# error: no matching function for call to 'FaceDetector::FaceDetector(std::__cxx11::string)'

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I am new to C++ and i am getting error like

```
error: no matching function for call to 'FaceDetector::FaceDetector(std::__cxx11::string)'
     FaceDetector fd(string(DEFAULT_CASCADE_PATH));
```

and i am attaching my code and error log how to fix this please guide me

```
#define DEFAULT_CASCADE_PATH "cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
#define ORIGINALS_LIST "obama_raw/list"
#define OUTPUT_DIR "obama_faces"
#define OUTPUT_LIST "list"
#define FACE_SIZE Size(150,150)
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include "cv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "FaceDetector.h"
using namespace std; 
using namespace cv;

void read_input_list(const string &list_path, vector<Mat> &images) {
    ifstream file(list_path.c_str());
    string path;
    while (getline(file, path)) {
        images.push_back(imread(path));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FaceDetector fd(string(DEFAULT_CASCADE_PATH));
    vector<Mat> raw_faces;
    ofstream out_list(format("%s/%s", OUTPUT_DIR, OUTPUT_LIST).c_str());
    read_input_list(string(ORIGINALS_LIST), raw_faces);
    int img_c = 0; //images counter

//now detect the faces in each of the raw images:
    for (vector<Mat>::const_iterator raw_img = raw_faces.begin() ; raw_img != raw_faces.end() ; raw_img++){
        vector<Rect> faces;
        //detect faces in the image (there should be only one):
        fd.findFacesInImage(*raw_img, faces);

        //cut each face and write to disk:
        for (vector<Rect>::const_iterator face = faces.begin() ; face != faces.end() ; face++){
            int edge_size = max(face->width, face->height);
            Rect square(face->x, face->y, edge_size, edge_size);
            Mat face_img = (*raw_img)(square);

            //resize:
            resize(face_img, face_img, FACE_SIZE);

            //write to disk:
            string face_path = format("%s/%d.jpg", OUTPUT_DIR, img_c++);
            imwrite(face_path,face_img);
            out_list << face_path << endl;
        }
    }
    out_list.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and i am attaching my error log.Please can any one help. 
Thanks in advance

Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZXXK.jpg

Comment: I can't seem to find any references to a `FaceDetector` class in the OpenCV documentation. Where did you get it from? What header files are you including? Please edit your question include a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply i am using header files#define DEFAULT_CASCADE_PATH "cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
#define ORIGINALS_LIST "obama_raw/list"
#define OUTPUT_DIR "obama_faces"
#define OUTPUT_LIST "list"
#define FACE_SIZE Size(150,150)

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include "cv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "FaceDetector.h"

Comment: Oh and when you **edit your question** to include the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output of the compiler. Errors such as the one you show often include informational messages as well, that will tell what possible alternatives there are.

Comment: Again, *please* show us the *full* error output. And tell us what this `FaceDetector` class is (and perhaps even show us the `FaceDetector.h` header file). And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Copy-paste text *as text*. Don't post links (that can go stale) to images. *However* there you can see what the `FaceDetector` constructor expects, a string *and* some other values, which you don't provide. That's why you get the error, you don't provide enough arguments. Perhaps you should take some time to read the `FaceDetector` *documentation*? Or at least its source?

Answer (score 0):

From GCC 5, A new ABI is enabled by default. In that new ABI, std::__cxx11 namesapce was introduced.

According to your error message, It seems that your program and OpenCV library you want to link with were build with different GCC version, which made incompatible binary.

For more information, you can read the following page:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: That would result in a *linker* error about "undefined references" or similar, not a compiler error which the OP have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I agree with you.

Comment: I am not getting any linker errors so this is not the correct solution for me but thanks for your information definitly it helps in another times